# Can I manually update the React version in my React Native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a 0.69.1 React Native app that came with React 18.0.0. Are these versions pinned to each other, or is it okay to update React to 18.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

React Native 0.69.1 has a peer dependency on React with version `"18.0.0"` (exactly that version) (from [`package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.69-stable/package.json#L96)). So the short answer is no, you cannot change
the version of React to 18.2.0 while keeping React Native at 0.69.1.

It looks like RN 0.70.x is going to have a peer dependency on React with version `"18.1.0"` (again from [`package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.70-stable/package.json#L97)), so you can update both when RN 0.70.0 is released.